# Param used by Webpack for IIFE on output bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, iife

I'm trying to understand the output of a webpack bundle. Everything looks understandable except the following snippet. I know the `()()` pattern but I would like to know why they put a `0` as first parameter.

```
(0, _jquery2.default)('<li></li>').text('foo').appendTo(ul);
```

Doing tests I see that no matter how many params you pass it always will return the last param. so if I do

```
(0, 'foo', function(arg){console.log(arg)})('bar')
-> bar
```

It will return `bar`.

Why they do this way? Maybe strict mode has to do with this?

Comment: So far I found something similar on wikipedia:

"In contexts where an expression is expected, wrapping in parentheses is not necessary:"

`0, function () { … }();`

Comment: thank you @slindberg that's exactly what I wanted to know.